# What is a solution to the recurrence relation $f(n) = f(n-1) +f\Big(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\Big)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

> Let $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  Find a closed form or an asymptotic form of  $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, where $f$ satisfies $f(1) = 1$ and $$f(n) = f(n-1) + f\bigg(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\bigg)\,.$$

What is a closed-form solution to this recurrence relation?

Neither the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), nor its generalization, the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), seem to be applicable.

Comment: Is this your question?  It wasn't clear what you wanted to me.  I realized after making the edit.  Do you want a closed form, or an asymptotic form?

Comment: I was thinking of a closed form, but now that you say it, an asymptotic solution would be sufficient as well. Or even a decent lower bound. Really anything that gives some intuition about the growth rate of this function.

Comment: I tried to see whether there is a nice analytic approximation, but then I encountered the differential equation $p'(x)=p\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$, which seems to be quite difficult to solve.

Comment: This is [OEIS A033485](https://oeis.org/A033485), about which not much seems to be known. It’s half of [OEIS A000123](https://oeis.org/A000123) (with first term omitted), about which a bit more seems to be available.